# An index set for a limit has very few morphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm just learning about limits. My book (Kashiwara/Schapira) defines projective limits on sets in the following way: Suppose $F \in [I^{\text{op}} , \text{Sets}]$. Then 
$$\varprojlim F:= \text{Hom}_{[I^{\text{op}},\text{Sets}]}(\Delta_{\text{pt}}, F),$$

where $\Delta_{\text{pt}}$ is the constant functor at the set $\{*\}$. Thus $\varprojlim F$ can be viewed as an subset of $\prod\limits_{i}F(i)$. (I believe this is somewhat different from the way it is usually defined, though equivalent.)

My question is: it seems that the elements of $\varprojlim F \subseteq \prod\limits_iF(i)$ that are present must be very few, unless $I$ has hardly any morphisms at all. For instance, if $s \in F(i)$ is such that there exist $\omega, \eta \in \text{Hom}_{I^{\text{op}}}(j,i)$ such that $F(\omega)(s) \neq F(\eta)(s)$, then $\alpha_i \neq s$ for any $\alpha \in \varprojlim F$. In particular, if there exists an $i$ such that all the elements of $F(i)$ are like $s$ above, then $\varprojlim F$ must be the empty set.

Is this right? So we mostly have to choose $I$ to have few morphisms (like in the case of the product where $I$ is discrete)?

Comment: What is $\Delta_{pt}$?

Comment: @Berci Just edited. Sorry, forgot to explain that.

Comment: FYI, you can write $\varprojlim$ as `\varprojlim` (it looks better than $\lim\limits_{\leftarrow}$ and it's easier to write).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thank you! What does one write for the inductive limit?

Comment: `\varinjlim` gives $\varinjlim$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying mathematically is correct, but the conclusion is wrong (or at least, hard to judge since there is no precise meaning of "few morphisms"). Better look at some classical examples first ($p$-adics $\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim_n ~ \mathbb{Z}/p^n$) before diving into general category theory.

Comment: In that case $I = \mathbb{N}$, right? So with a unique morphism between any two elements, it seems there are very few morphisms there.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "few". In total there are countably many morphisms. In any case, your question doesn't seem to be a mathematical one ...

Comment: You're right; I could have been more clear. I meant to say: Am I correct that if there exist multiple morphisms $(i\to j) \in \text{Hom}_{I}$, and $F$ is faithful, then it makes it difficult for the limit to exist?

Comment: No. Consider for example $I^{op}=\{\bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet\}$. A diagram of this shape is $\{A \rightrightarrows B\}$, it is faithful when the two maps are different. But still the limit i.e. the equalizer of the two maps may be any proper subset of $A$. As I've said, you should really look at examples, even if the topic is "abstract nonsense".